# Show that $ \frac{F(q+h)-F(q) -hF'(q)}{h} \sim \frac{h}{2}F''(q)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I am reading a book where the author argues without particular rigour, that for fixed $q$ and $h \downarrow0$ it holds that
$$ \frac{F(q+h)-F(q) -hF'(q)}{h} \sim \frac{h}{2}F''(q)$$

This is what I do to get the result. By the mean value theorem $F(q+h)-F(q)=F'(c(h))(q+h-h)=hF'(c(h))$ where $c(h) \in (q,q+h)$. Then we get 
$$ \frac{F(q+h)-F(q) -hF'(q)}{h} =\frac{h \left( F'(c(h))-F'(q)\right)}{h} $$
Now, further arguing that $c(h)\rightarrow q$ as $h \downarrow0$, we get $$\frac{h \left( F'(c(h))-F'(q)\right)}{h} \sim hF''(q)$$

So my question is, how does the author get the constant $\frac{1}{2}$. Of course, it does not matter from asymptotic point of view, but how does it appear? You can assume that $F$ is sufficiently smooth for your arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{F(q+h)-F(q) -hF'(q)}{h} 
\sim \frac{h}{2}F''(q)
$

Starting with Taylor's theorem,
$f(q+h)
\sim f(q)+hf'(q)+h^2f''(q)/2+O(h^3)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{f(q+h)-f(q) -hf'(q)}{h} 
&\sim\dfrac{f(q)+hf'(q)+h^2f''(q)/2+O(h^3)-f(q) -hf'(q)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{h^2f''(q)/2+O(h^3)}{h}\\
&=hf''(q)/2+O(h^2)\\
\end{array}
$

Actually,
I would write this as
$\dfrac{f(q+h)-f(q) -hf'(q)}{h^2}
 =f''(q)/2+O(h)
$;
otherwise both sides
go to zero.

Comment: Marty, if all we know is that the second derivative exists at $q$, then we should replace $O(h^3)$ with $o(h^2)$.  The result is unaffected since $o(1)\to 0$ as $h\to0$.

Comment: Yup, but I always assume enough to make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your argument is that $c(h)$ may converge to $q$ quickly, so the final assumption isn't necessarily valid.  One way you could argue this is straight from Taylor's theorem, and you see this is just the second order term.  Of course, this is in fact a simpler case of Taylor's theorem, which you can prove using the mean value theorem itself, indicating there should be a shorter proof.  The argument [here](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/taylors-theorem-with-the-lagrange-form-of-the-remainder/), gives a nice inductive proof of Taylor's theorem, and stopping for the right value of $k$ would prove just what you're looking for.

It's worth pointing out that $h \to 0$ is enough, you don't particularly require $h \downarrow 0$ only, unless of course you're dealing with one-sided differentiability.

Comment: Could you give a an example where $c(h)$ converges to q quickly? Isn't smoothness enough to exclude it?

Comment: The type of thing I mean is where, say, $c(h) = h/2$, so $(F'(c(h)) - F'(q))/h$ turns out to be closer to $2F''(q)$ instead of $F''(q)$.  Smoothness doesn't help at all here in terms of the approximation.